# Workflow to send an Email from a single line text field

Tags: designer-workflow

I am unable to create a workflow here it could pickup the email address from a single line text field. This an external email address. so the people or group option does not work. since it gets converted to microsoftonline id.

This email ID is manually entered. I have sharepoint 365 and i have sharepoint 2010 has a workflow platform.

Regards,
Charles Thangaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-  Create a workflow local variable as string**
[image]

**2-  Set the variable with the text value (email address)** 
From **Action** Menu under **core actions** click **“Set Workflow Variable”**
[image]
Select the Variable, then click on **Value**, click on the **fx** button.
Choose the data source **“Current Item”** and field from source select your text field, then click **OK** 
[image]

**3-  In send email action , set TO field with the variable and return the field as Email Address**

[image] 
hope this answers your question

Comment: This was helpful. I was able to send email to the external email address using this method